# Angular index.html not loading by default

Tags: angular

My index.html not loading by default. Site is loading the parent directory. Below is the example of my `index.html`:

```
<base href="/TEST/">
```

My URL Rewrite entry:

```
/TEST/
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTr4V.png)

Can someone please help with the solution?

`https://servername/TEST/` -> this url should open the `index.html` page

Comment: This seems to be a problem of host configuration. The Angular app is compiled already in your screen capture. Try moving the files to the parent folder, or configure the server properly.

Comment: when you build the app you can change the base href: `ng build  --base-href=TEST`

Comment: Now the issue I see is.. When I navigate to my url -"servername/Internal/index.html" - It resolves to "servername/Internal" .However, when I refresh the url "servername/Internal" It gives 404. This is my web.config - <action type="Rewrite" url="/Internal/" /> and this is my index.html entry - <title>Internal</title> <base href="/Internal/"> – 
Chandan Sethi

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to change in `index.html` file. Just use Angular's [`APP_BASE_HREF`](https://angular.io/api/common/APP_BASE_HREF#app_base_href) DI token.

Please refer the [link](https://angular.io/api/common/APP_BASE_HREF#app_base_href) from Angular official website for usage.

Comment: This is [the same](https://angular.io/api/common/PathLocationStrategy#description) as `<base href="">`

Comment: Now the issue I see is.. When I navigate to my url -"https://servername/Internal/index.html" - It resolves to "https://servername/Internal/" .However, when I refresh the url "https://servername/Internal/" It gives 404. This is my web.config - <action type="Rewrite" url="/Internal/" /> and this is my index.html entry - <title>Internal</title>
  <base href="/Internal/">